# UnityEngine Color errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Errors: 'NetHack.HacksCalculator.Color(r) is a 'method' which is not valid in the given context

```
private bool bChams = false;
private Color CrossColor = Color.green;
private Color EspPlayer = Color.green;
private Color Weapons = Color.green;
```

i don't know why they happen

Comment: Are you trying to set objects to the color green? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html

Comment: In which line the compiler complains?

Comment: it's long code, at many lines where is color.white, color.red etc errors

Comment: Do you have a method in there sharing name with the `Color` structure, shadowing it? If you right-click on `Color` and say *Go to definition* do you land in a correct place?

Comment: it takes me to HacksCalculator.RGBColor where there is always error at line => always there is ; expected and it keeps giving same error even if i place there ;

Comment: This really sounds to me like a name collision. Do you have anything named `Color` in your namespace?

Comment: no i don't have anything named Color
anyway removing => in RGBColor Fixed some errors but then more of them appeared

Answer (score 1):

you are using NetHack.* so the code thinks you are using `NetHack.HacksCalculator.Color(r)` that is a method but you want to use the `Color` Struct in `UnityEngine` so you should specify that in the code, you can do it like this

```
private UnityEngine.Color CrossColor = UnityEngine.Color.green;
```